# Importing packages works but still get errors?

Tags: python, import, package, sys

I have a Python application that conforms to the MVC model so I have folders called `Controller, Model and View`. In each of these folders I have Python files that I import into each other. It seems to work however when you hover the cursor over the import I see the `"Unable to import XXXX"` error and I am not sure why this is.

I have an empty `__init__` file in each folder and have added the path to system path.

The directory of my application goes like this:

```
    Desktop/Application--¬
                          Controller--¬
                                       MainController.py
                                       GraphEngine.py
                                       APIMethods.py
                          Model-------¬
                                       MainModel.py
                                       DatabaseAccess.py
                          View
```

I use `import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/Data-Processing-Engine-Sorted/Controller')`
to set the system path and then use `import MainController` to actually gain access to the file.

This seems to work fine. The other file locates MainController and uses its methods with no issue, however in the IDE I can't get rid of the `"Unable to import MainController"` error. I am really quite confused as to why.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Try adding a PYTHONPATH environment variable pointing to the directory. Also are you using virtual environment in the IDE?

Comment: Ah I'm not a work computer right now with no admin rights so I can't add them to my path and no I'm not using a virtual environment. I'm new to Python so I don't really know anything about virtual environments.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS Code

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue! It's very simple and quite embarrassing...

When calling one of the methods I was only calling the module rather than the class, for example:

`controller = MainController()` Would return with an error while

`controller = MainController.MainController()` Would create an instance of my class